# ORMLite and Foreign Keys Constraints in PostgreSQL

Tags: foreign-keys, ormlite

I am using TableUtils to generate my tables with ORMLite. Everything is working just fine if I use ORMLite for all operations. However, when I try to perform a join query using something else, it complains about missing foreign key relationship.

If I look in the database, I can see that the column is not set to be a foreign key.

I defined the relationship using the following annotation:

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, foreignColumnName="id")
protected CoatedSampleEntity coatedSample;
```

Is there anyway to get the TableUtil to flag this fields as a foreign key when I generate the tables?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately as of May 2013, the answer is "no".  ORMLite does not support foreign-key constraints.    You can set them up yourself with the [`@DatabaseField(columnDefinition("..."))` field](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#columnDefinition%28%29).